# Convert 60 or more minutes to hours

Tags: c#, time

I have two variables that hold hours and minutes. I want to round off the time if the minutes variable is = 60 minutes.

So if hours = 3, minutes = 60, I want to return hours = 4, and minutes = 00. Is there a time function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming both `hours` and `minutes` are `int`):

```
  hours += minutes / 60;
  minutes %= 60;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is really trivial to implement:

```
while (minutes >= 60)
{
    minutes -= 60;
    hours += 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this...had something similar and but had minutes > 60 as condition instead of minutes >= 60 and thought my calculations were wrong.

Comment: @Lucky that's why you should show your code in your question, someone else could've spotted that mistake easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create own struct/class to store time with custom getter/setter

for example

```
    struct myTimeStruct
    {
        public int minutes
        {
            get { return minutes; }
            set
            {
                minutes = minutes % 60;
                hours += minutes / 60;
            }
        }

        private int hours
        {
            get { return hours; }
            set { hours = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class:

```
var hours = 3;
var minutes = 60;

var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
var totalHours = timeSpan.TotalHours;
```